# separated object does not match the original object after separation

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, faces, bevel

I would like to separate the back of this speaker into a separate object. The original Object has two Bevel and one Subdiv Modifyer attached but not applied

[image]

But after separation the new object does not exactly match the shape of thew original object anymore. There is an overlap around the corners.

[image]

I applied all Transformers before separation, I removed Bevel around the connecting edge, I added and removed Bevel around the connecting edge, I deleted the faces at the connecting side.

The only thing that worked, was applying the first bevel in the modifyer stack of the original object before separation and separate the new object already with the Bevel applied but then of course you lose the option to apply the modifyer later.
Is there a chance to separate the back in such a case without having to apply the modifyer first but still getting an exactly matching new object?

Comment: hello could you please share your object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Should be uploaded now.

Comment: you need to copy paste the link (URL) it will give you

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/c7b20d4ab69745dc97a16238e5041cc6

Comment: Have you tried separating the backside of the speaker? The front side is not the problem. I Already separated the front side and this one is matching just fine although I do not know what the difference to the back side is.  However I would prefere not having to apply the Modifyers yet. Neither before, nor after separating. I am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: oh ok it's the Loop Slide option of the first Bevel modifier that makes a difference between the main and the separate part

Comment: @ Simon Julian, you need to correct the front topology if you don't want to keep your Bevel modifier and don't want a bad topology

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Loop Slide* option of your first *Bevel* modifier creates a larger bevel  as the front is larger than the back. Disable it and rework the front part a bit so that it doesn't mess your topology.

[image]